# Pause and send HTTP post on Android outgoing call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, http-post

I am making an app that when an outgoing call is made to a certain number (let's call it 123456789), It will attempt to send an HTTP post to a URL with a few digits and wait for an OK, then let the call through.

However, if this HTTP POST takes longer than, say, 4 seconds, then we add the digits as DTMFs on the outgoing number.

The issue is that, on Android, the Main Thread shouldn't (or can't) be put to sleep, or 
else the phone will become unresponsive and then crash, so I need to find a wait to delay the call being made by 4 seconds, while I do the POST.

Here's an idea of what the code would look like. I'm not going for the specific code lines but I am more trying to figure out how to make the phone wait for the result of the Post before putting the call through.

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context pContext, Intent intent) {

Context context = pContext;
String action = intent.getAction();

String digitsToSend = ",1234";
String outgoingNumber = getResultData();

if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) 
    && isNetworkAvailable(pContext) 
        && outgoingNumber.equals("123456789") {

    try{
        //We set a HTTPConnection with timeouts, so it fails if longer than 4     seconds
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 2000);  // allow 2 seconds to create the server connection
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 2000);  // and another 2 seconds to retreive the data
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
       if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
            //Success
            setResultData(outgoingNumber);
       }

    } catch (Exception e){
            //Took too long, sending digits as DTMFs
        setResultData(outgoingNumber+digitsToSend);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possible solutions:
Either use callbacks and implement them within a method you call from your main activity so that when the request ends, you can proceed with the code from there. (the best solution)
Or you can also go along with countdownlatch, which is basically like a red traffic light that "stops" the code until you release it. Here's how it works:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);  // param 1 is the number of times you have to latch.countDown() in order to unlock code bottleneck below.

latch.countDown();  // when you trigger this as many times as set above, latch.await() will stop blocking the code


try {
            latch.await();    //wherever u want to stop the code
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
    }
```